# React/Redux connect does not fire mapStateToProps on store change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am experiencing an issue with Redux (used along with React). Here is my code:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts"/>

import "./polyfill.ts";

import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { Provider, dispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRedirect } from 'react-router'
import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'

import { Form, Input } from './components/form.tsx'

import app from './reducers.ts'

const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        app,
        routing: routerReducer
    }),
    {},
    window.devToolsExtension && window.devToolsExtension()
);

import App from './views/app.tsx';
import Reminders from './views/reminders.tsx';
import Calendar from './views/calendar.tsx';
import Settings from './views/settings.tsx';
import Groups from './views/groups.tsx';
import Courses from './views/courses.tsx';
import Homework from './views/homework.tsx';

// Create an enhanced history that syncs navigation events with the store
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

class Application extends React.Component<any,any> {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        var socket = io();
        socket.on('connect', function () {
            setTimeout(function(){
                store.dispatch({
                    type: "SOCKET_ESTABLISHED",
                    socket: socket
                });
            }, 1000);
        });
        socket.on('DATA', function(data){
            console.log("DATA");
            console.log(data);
        })
        console.log(Groups);
        return <Provider store={store}>
            <Router history={history}>
                <Route path="/" component={App}>
                    <IndexRedirect to="/reminders" />
                    <Route path="reminders" component={Reminders}/>
                    <Route path="calendar" component={Calendar}/>
                    <Route path="settings" component={Settings}>
                        <Route path="groups" component={Groups}/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="homework" component={Homework} />
                </Route>
            </Router>
        </Provider>
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <Application/>,
    document.getElementById('mount')
);
```

My reducer file looks like the following:

```
    export default function app(state={
        connection: {
            socket: null,
            online: false
        }
    }, action: any) {
        console.log(action);
        switch(action.type){
            case "SOCKET_ESTABLISHED":
                console.log(state.connection);
                return Object.assign(state, {
                    connection: {
                        socket: action.socket,
                        online: true
                    }
                });
            default:
                return state;
        }
    };
```

And my App component is the following:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Top from '../components/top.tsx';
import Nav from '../components/nav.tsx';

class AppClass extends React.Component<any,any> {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render() : JSX.Element {
        return <div>
            <Top/>
            <Nav/>
            {this.props.connection.online ? this.props.children : "Offline." }
        </div>
    }
}

var App = connect(function(state){
    return {
        connection: state.app.connection
    };
})(AppClass);

export default App;
```

So let me be clear, I am using the connect function to sync store and App props. Upon page load, a socket connection is created and the action SOCKET_ESTABLISHED which changes `store.connection.online` to `true`. Everything works fine, the Redux dev tools show that the store is correctly updated and online is now true. If I look with the React dev tools the `Connect(AppClass)` component, its storeState is up to date, but its child component, which is AppClass, does not have the right props, `this.props.app.connection.online` is false where it should be true. I have seen that it could come from a state mutation, but using Object.assign a new store is returned (The function is the [MDN Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill)).

Hope I was clear and thank you !

(Note that I am using Typescript for compiling although I might have been neglecting some interface definitions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're modifying the state object inside of the reducer. You need to copy state to a new object, and then modify the new one.

Update this:

```
return Object.assign(state, {
    connection: {
        socket: action.socket,
        online: true
    }
});
```

To this:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
    connection: {
        socket: action.socket,
        online: true
    }
});

// or this
return {
    ...state,
    connection: {
        socket: action.socket,
        online: true
    }
}
```

Redux receives the new state from the reducer and compares it to the previous state. If you modify the state directly, the new state and previous state are *the same object*. It's similar to doing this.

```
var state = { foo: 'bar' };
state.test = 'test';
var newState = state;
// state === newState # true
```

Instead, you want to copy the object before modifying

```
var state = { foo: 'bar' };
var newState = { ...state, test: 'test' };
// state === newState # false
```

Answer (score 0):

mapStateToProps function must return new state object to triger rerender of the component.

Try changing

```
return state
```

to

```
return {...state}
```

Comment: Actually Typescript wont compile correctly three-dots operator, thus I am going to update my question with an explicit object naming. Anyway, thank you for your help !